# Collections of event dates of politicians doing things in the USA or across the world?

Tags: data-request, politics

I stumbled across [this list of Trump's record on the military and vets](https://www.reddit.com/r/politics/comments/18fgl64/comment/kcw5bgd/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) posted on Reddit, which is about ~50 or so events on things he did relative to the military/vets while president I think.

Do any other such aggregated "data sets" exist out there for other politicians? Basically any documented / curated collection of events exactly like in that list (though it can be formatted differently).

If not, what is the next best bet other than scowering through news articles? I guess asking ChatGPT might help produce some lists of up to 40-50 events at a time, but at the same time I wouldn't know just by glancing at the results if they were accurate or hallucinating, so probably not the best resource out there.

Comment: As it's about politics, any such list has the risk of being voluntarily biased (e.g. omitting some facts). Even if such lists have been curated by people of good faith, they should use the same criteria for inclusion/exclusion in order to be comparable (e.g. do two quotations about veterans in the same speech count as two occurrences, or one occurrence? Reasonable people may disagree on that, which can make it difficult to compare 2 sources). If anything, I'd look for a single source without potential partisanship motivations, maybe some veteran association. ChatGPT would be a terrible option.